# What paintings might these be (2 sketches made in the Tate Britain Gallery)?

Tags: identification, art, painting

[image]

My daughter drew these two sketches in the Tate Britain Gallery. She needs to complete the sketches but cannot remember which paintings they are based upon.

She has looked through the Tate Britain website but to no avail.

Could you please help her by identifying the paintings the sketches are based upon?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The top one might be [Thomas Daniell, Idgah at Amroha  1810](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/daniell-idgah-at-amroha-t01404)

[image]

While the bottom one is [John Linnell, Kensington Gravel Pits 1811–2](https://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/linnell-kensington-gravel-pits-n05776)

[image]

<sub>Both images are [copyright](https://www.tate-images.com/faqs.asp?#HowDoICaptionArtisticWork): © Tate under CC-BY-NC-ND 3.0 (Unported)</sub>

Comment: Doubtless correct.  Did you recognise these from memory, or did you have an effective way of searching for them?

Comment: I realised that the pictures had to be currently on display, so I browsed the British art collection walk through on the Tate website. For the first picture I was looking for the distinctive tree on the right, and for the second, I looked for the wagon in the centre.